# How can I use the font family 'Lato' in my project?

Tags: css, font-family, google-font-api

I have used the style like this in my .css file but it is not working. What can I do to make my code work?

```
font-family: Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

link:  http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato

Comment: is this font is present in ur Fonts folder in C drive?

Comment: All the information you need is given on the Google fonts page for [this font](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Lato). You might need to scroll down a bit.

Comment: @MikeW, +1, that should have been an answer.

Comment: can you download it I can tell you how to install at your website'

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Please put this code in head section

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and use `font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;` in your css. For example:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

**Or you can use manually also**

Generate `.ttf` font from `fontSquiral`

and can try this option

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Lato";
        src: url('698242188-Lato-Bla.eot');
        src: url('698242188-Lato-Bla.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('698242188-Lato-Bla.svg#Lato Black') format('svg'),
        url('698242188-Lato-Bla.woff') format('woff'),
        url('698242188-Lato-Bla.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}
```

Called like this

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Your answer help me to get the Lato light font (using size 300)

Comment: yes you can choose font-family from here http://prntscr.com/83rkv9

Comment: I tried many ways but it worked once I added 'sans-serif' part....

Comment: yes, its sans-serif font so we need to use

Comment: If this works for you in all browsers except Chrome, change `http` to `https`.

Comment: Yes, you are right mate

Comment: I know this is a very old answer, but consider changing `http://` to `https://`, because secure pages won't load fonts from an insecure html.

Comment: Yea, you are right.

Answer (score 19):

Download it from [here](http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/) and extract `LatoOFL.rar` then go to TTF and open this [font-face-generator](http://www.font-face-generator.com/) click at `Choose File` choose font which you want to use and click at generate then download it and then go `html` file open it and you see the code like this

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "Lato Black";
        src: url('698242188-Lato-Bla.eot');
        src: url('698242188-Lato-Bla.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('698242188-Lato-Bla.svg#Lato Black') format('svg'),
        url('698242188-Lato-Bla.woff') format('woff'),
        url('698242188-Lato-Bla.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}
body{
    font-family: "Lato Black";
    direction: ltr;
}
```

change the src code and give the url where your this font directory placed, now you can use it at your website...

If you don't want to download it use this

```
<link type='text/css' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' />
```

Comment: No i want to use in my website .

Comment: font face generator is a good idea